# Headless Chrome and Selenium on Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've seen that headless Chrome came out in some form last month and I've seen that it can be interacted with via Selenium but the articles I've seen mostly mention Linux and MacOS. Is this available for windows (7 and /or 10) yet?

Answer (score 5):

The Headless mode for Windows is available in Chrome 60 **beta**, and the stable version is likely to be also in the 60th version.

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html

There are no differences in the launch of Selenium

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I use it on windows but with version 59 (beta) there is still an empty window popping up.

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this yet? I'm also having this problem.

Comment: An empty Chrome window?

Comment: version 59 in the sense is it related to chrome version you are taking about I mean chrome 59?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Chrome in headless mode for months, with Chrome 59 on Windows.

My Karma config (for a custom Chrome headless) is as follows:

```
browsers: ['Chrome_headless'],
customLaunchers: {
    Chrome_headless: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-plugins', '--window-size=0,0', '--window-position=-9999,0']
    }
},
```

There is no visible window with these commands.

However, updating to Chrome 60 seems to have killed this config as it no longer works (as of today)

Comment: I'm currently trying out headless mode with selenium and find that test runs are taking far longer to launch and start. Do you see this as well?

Comment: @rossisdead I have seen that issue, but not with Karma or selenium, only BrowserSync, and I was able to fix that with a minor config change

Comment: would you mind telling me what that minor config change was? I'd like to try it out

Comment: sure, it was `--no-online` and that had an immediate and very apparent effect :)

Comment: Thanks! Sadly didn't seem to make any difference for me

Answer (score 1):

I am using Chromedriver headless mode with the version [2.33](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/) with the following config for Capybara:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_headless do |app|
  args = ["--window-size=1280,1696", "--no-sandbox", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-infobars", "--disable-notifications"]  
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :args => args})
end
```

Answer (score -1):

It's working right now in chrome 59 with chromedriver 2.31 (just released). The only annoying thing is an empty window popping up at the beginning (just a visual effect) which will be removed in chrome 60 (should be about to release)

Comment: chromedriver 2.30 is now available..https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.30/

Comment: Windows headless support will come with chrome 61 (not even beta at this moment)