# Selenium (Java) with Headless Chrome on Windows 7

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, headless

- Chrome version 61.0.3163.100
- Chromedriver Version 2.32
- Selenium-Java version 3.5.3
- OS: Windows 7

I can get the Selenium Test running without a window popping up, however it always fails at the first step saying it can't find the element I am looking for.

The Driver setup code looks like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("headless");
options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
```

I have my Selenium Tests set up to take a screenshot on failure. The screenshot always shows a white empty screen (which is exactly as large as the window-size I provide).

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880619/headless-chrome-and-selenium-on-windows) it is said that headless chrome should work fine on Windows.

I have tried the `disable-gpu` argument as well which has no effect. Any other ideas where I could be going wrong?

Comment: try with latest chrome!!

Comment: same result with version 61.0.3163.100

Comment: have tried adding `disable-gpu`?? seems works with windows 7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880619/headless-chrome-and-selenium-on-windows#43880709

Comment: yes I already mentioned that in my question :)

Comment: I mean with the latest version!!

Comment: yes, same result. I think I might have found the problem: insecure SSL (i am using https on localhost), see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused by chrome complaining about my self-signed dev certificate on https pages. Obviously a white page in your screenshot isn't very intuitive lol
The fix was to add the certificate as a trusted certificate to the trusted root certs.

Note: as of chrome 58 identifying the host using only ‘commonName’ is being removed so if you're getting the Err_cert_common_name_invalid error just re-generate your certificate with whatever method and make sure you include the 'subjectAltName' with proper DNS and IP entry.